# keep track of rows in data table when sub setting

Tags: r, datatable

Minimal example:

```
dt <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6))
```

That looks like that:

```
>  dt
   a b
1: 1 4
2: 2 5
3: 3 6
```

If I want to get the indices of rows where a value is greater or equal to `5` I can use:

```
> dt[,rowSums(dt>=5) > 0]
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

or the rows themselves but the row indices are gone in this case:

```
> dt[rowSums(dt>=5) > 0]
   a b
1: 2 5
2: 3 6
```

So I went ahead and created a new column to keep track of the row:

```
dt <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6),row=c('row1','row2','row3'))
```

new dt is:

```
> dt
   a b  row
1: 1 4 row1
2: 2 5 row2
3: 3 6 row3
```

Now if I want to use the same approach the subset no longer works:

```
> dt[,rowSums(dt>=5) > 0]
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

My intention is to use either `rowSums` or `ColSums` and still be able to keep track of the rows. In this example would be:

```
> dt
1: 2 5 row2
2: 3 6 row3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your own way of sub-setting, and assuming that the column which keeps track of the rows are always at the end of your data frame. Then you can choose to only apply the "rowsum" on selected columns, like so

```
dt <- data.table(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6),row=c('row1','row2','row3'))

dt[rowSums(dt[, 1:(ncol(dt)-1)]>=5) > 0]
```

Comment: key is to exclude the columns with non-numeric values, since this will mess up the rowSums output. Easiest to use `.SDcols` with `is.numeric()`, like: `dt[rowSums(dt[, .SD, .SDcols = is.numeric] >= 5) >= 1,]`

Comment: that is great but `dt[,colSums(dt[, .SD, .SDcols = is.numeric] >= 5) >= 1]` doesn't work this way

Comment: ok got it, `dt[rowSums(dt[, .SD, .SDcols = is.numeric] >= 5) > 0, c(colSums(dt[,.SD,.SDcols=is.numeric] >= 5) > 0,T), with=F]`